# Problem in dynamic grid view

Tags: asp.net

I ve a grid view created dynamically. And each cell of the grid view has textboxes that are created dynamically.. The values for the textbox comes from  an xml file and the IDs of the Text Boxes come from database.

The problem is, the values(to be displayed in text box) are getting assigned when i check using break points but not getting displayed in the output.

Comment: can you post the relevant code & code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post code, but... Here's a guess: if the values are not in the output, then they are probably being assigned *after* the ASP.NET Render event.  You need to set the values when you create the controls.